# how to make evil-leader local in org-src-mode?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, evil

I use evil-mode and evil-leader, and I have the `<SPC>s` keybinding to save the buffer. But when I edit a src code block in org-mode (with `C-'`), I want `<SPC>s` to run `org-edit-src-save` instead of `save-buffer`. Some things I tried:

```
;; I think this one has no effect because `set-key-for-mode`
;; probably only works with major-modes.
(evil-leader/set-key-for-mode 'org-src-mode "s" 'org-edit-src-save)


;; This one works, but makes the binding global.
(defun my/org-src-conf () 
 (make-local-variable 'evil-leader--default-map)
 (make-local-variable 'evil-leader--mode-maps)
 (evil-leader/set-key "s" 'org-edit-src-save))

(add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook 'my/org-src-conf)
```

How can I achieve this local binding for evil-leader?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using `evil-leader` instead of the keymap support Emacs comes with?

Comment: None other than `evil-leader` seems the right way to do it. Also, I didn't just use the `evil-define-key` because I want to learn how to actually achieve this. I'm trying to understand emacs better.

Answer (score 2):

`org-src-mode` is a minor mode and evil-leader doesn't support these last time I checked. `evil-leader/set-key-for-mode` is for major modes. In `org-src-mode` the major mode is tied to the language of the source that you are editing.

The most natural way to accomplish what you want is to use `evil-define-minor-mode-key` with the following.

```el
(evil-define-minor-mode-key 'normal 'org-src-mode " s" 'org-edit-src-exit)
```

You can use `evil-define-key` too, but it does not always activate the key bindings for keys in maps connected to minor modes.